# RDLC custom thousand separator?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I want to format number in a custom way thousand separator should be space and decimal separator is . sign.

ie. 10000000.20 should look like 10 000 000.20 and negative value -10 000 000.20

I have applied custom formatting like  ### ### ### ### ##0.00;-### ### ### ### ##0.00

but negative value comes with an extra space after -(minus) sign like - 100 000 000.20

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

One quick work-around for the extra space after the comma would be to Replace '- ' with '-' in the formatted string... (=Replace([formatted string],"- ","-")
It's not the cleanest way to do things, but it would work anyway.
The same approach should work for the custom separator problem as well...

Cheers - hope this helps.